# How can I give member a role with role id?

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
role = client.get_role("697037307060027482")
await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

I Tried this, but Error occurs.
How can I give a role vith role id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get guild and get role. Example:

```py
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx):
    role = client.get_guild(your_guild_id).get_role(your_role_id)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```